How to add type declaration files to a JavaScript library that supports the CommonJS and ESModule specifications?
I have created a JavaScript library and written a .d.ts type declaration file for it. I noticed that the types work well in frontend projects using the ES module specification, but once I use require to import the library, the types are lost. What should I do to make the .d.ts file provide accurate type hints in all cases?
In my .d.ts file, I use export declare const function_name to export types, and I have explicitly specified the path to the .d.ts file in package.json. I've looked at other libraries, and their authors seem to do the same thing. I'm not sure why the types don't work in CommonJS projects.
